# VBA : copy updating file without opening

Tags: excel, vba, updates

I would like open the file, refresh the data (automatically) and copy this updated file to another folder.

My code is :

```
Option Explicit
Public Duree As Date

Function FichierExiste(FPath As String) As Boolean

Dim NomF As String
NomF = Dir(FPath)
If NomF <> "" Then FichierExiste = True _
Else: FichierExiste = False

End Function


Sub Fermer()
Dim oFSO As Object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
.RefreshAll
.Save
.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Call 
oFSO.CopyFile("\\XXXX\Dossier_avant\Fichier.xlsm", "\\XXXX\Dossier_apres\", True)
End With
End Sub

Sub StartHeure()
Duree = Now + TimeValue("01:00:30")
Application.OnTime Duree, "Fermer"
End Sub
```

And on ThisWorkbook :

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If FichierExiste("\XXXX\Dossier_apres\Fichier.xlsm") = False Then
Call StartHeure
Else
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End If
End Sub
```

When I copied the updated file the function =today() remains not updated. I'm wondering where is the problem in my cod.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand your question... So, you refresh the workbook where the code is, save it and close. Does the code copy it from the 'Dossier_avant' to 'Dossier_apres'? If copied, do you try telling us that a formula from the closed file does not work when open the copied workbook in 'Dossier_apres'?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, 'Dossier_avant to 'Dossier_apres' and in 'Dossier_apres'  the result of the formula is not right. Thank you.

Comment: Did you press F9 (to calculate)? Is the formula in discussion correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru This formula (=today()) is updated automatically while opening the file. I would like to open the file, update this formula without clicking on the buttom and save the last result.

Comment: @FaneDuru the problem is that in final folder I don't have the last result. :(

Comment: I do not understand anything... This "last result" is only in your head, I am afraid :) `Today()` formula will always display the current date. Do you want it to be frozen on the date when you copy the workbook?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, exactly, I would like the data be frozen.

Comment: @FaneDuru My problem is that in 'Dossier_apres' I have the data that I had in 'Dossier_avnat' before the opening

Comment: @FaneDuru I suppose that I have a problem with  "copy" in my code.

Comment: You do not have any problem with the "copy". If you copy a workbook it will behave **exactly** like the target workbook, where has been copied from. I will post a piece of code to show you what is to be modified. In which cell this 'Today()` formula does exist?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, it's in J8

Comment: @FaneDuru Is it possible to freeze all cells in my workbook ?

Comment: "J2" does not exist of the workbook level. It should be in a sheet. Please, test the code I posted and do not forget to update `dateRng` at your real sheet/cell address. And everything can be 'frozen', but you should deliver this information in your question. To do that, your way of copying should be cancelled. You will firstly saveAs the workbook in the new location and then will transform all formulas in value. How many sheets does the workbook in discussion have?

Comment: Please, test the code I posted after Edit. It will transform all formulas in values. And send some feedback after testing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test this way of saving:

```
Sub Fermer()
 Dim oFSO As Object, dateRng As Range
 
 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set dateRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("my sheet").Range("J8") 'update here the range keeping the formula "=Now()" formula!
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 With ThisWorkbook
    .RefreshAll
    dateRng.value = dateRng.value
    .Save
    oFSO.CopyFile "\\XXXX\Dossier_avant\Fichier.xlsm", "\\XXXX\Dossier_apres\", True
    dateRng.Formula = "Now()"
    .Close , True 'it is saved before closing (to keep the formula
 End With
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Edited**:
The version to copy it without any formula:

```
Sub FermerNoFormula()
 Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  With wb
        .RefreshAll
        .saveas "\\XXXX\Dossier_apres\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            sh.UsedRange.value = sh.UsedRange.value
        Next sh
        .Close , True 'it is saved before closing
 End With
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can do 'update here the range keeping the formula "=Today()" formula! automatically please ? Beacause when I open the file I have the old date

Comment: For example, at 15:00 in my folde "Dossier_avant" I would like to have 12/07/2021 15:00 while opening. I freez and copy this file to folder "Dossier_après".

Comment: When, after, 5 min later, I open the file in "Dossier_avant", I would like to have 12/07/2021 15:05

Comment: seems that VBA can't do the update like that ? I'm looking for it 2d day :(

Comment: another question please : is it possible to close the file before the copying please ?

Comment: @Marie I am afraid that you do not understand too well the community rules related to asking a question, no offence... At what piece of code, from the above two, are you referring to? Then, you placed a question asking for something completely unclear and now you come with something completely not connected with the initial question. If you want the date to be interpreted as you say **now**, you should use "=Now()" formula, not "Today()". You must understand that we here, without seeing your workbook cannot offer solution referring to "what you like to have". We are not mind readers...

Comment: @Marie What do you mean by "when I open the file I have the old date"? Didn't you say to freeze the formula in the existing workbook? I updated the above code to work with `Now()` instead of `Today()`.

Comment: @Marie If you close the file, **where from to copy anything**? Then, again at what code version are you referring to? Please, edit your question and **clearly state, what you need**. Not understanding VBA is not a big problem, not being experienced, but not knowing to explain what you want is not so easy to be accepted... There are community rules which must previously be learned: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: I understand clearly my formula, the code is right.